# What improvements can be done in Custom Business Object Class of dotnetnuke?

Tags: reflection, interface, dotnetnuke

I worked on [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) in some projects and I find very much interesting Custom Business Object Class which is named as `CBO.vb` in the DotNetNuke project.

So I want to use this helper class in my other project also which is not in DotNetNuke but in `core asp.net` projects.

So I read about some important methods of this class which are majority used by me are:

1. **CBO.FillObject**
2. **FillCollection**

Now I am searching what are issues in this class that can be improved by me before I am going to use this class.

So I search this and found an interesting topic on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BusinessObjectHelper.aspx) which point out several issues like:

1. **business object and the fields in the database had to have the same name**
2. **FillCollection method returned an ArrayList**

So my question is there any other thing which can be solved before use like

**use reflection to create objects which are slower** for that they give [idea how to implement](http://www.charlesnurse.com/?tag=/cbo) this by using `The IHydratable Interface`

You can find [class here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/CMS/dotnetnuke/DotNetNuke/Common/Utilities/CBO.cs.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CBO is a useful class.  However if I were looking for a similar solution today, I would look to one of the new "Micro-ORMs" such as:

[Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)

[PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)

[Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

When applying such a light wrapper around the database, I am not sure that supporting different names in the DB and business objects is really a good idea.  It is a likely source of confusion.

Also there are already generic overloads for the FillCollection method which return `List<T>`.  The ArrayList versions are only there for backward compatibility, no one should write any new code with them.